# Removing punctuation from string in Perl

Tags: perl, string

How do I remove all punctuation except for spaces from a string in Perl?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
s/[[:punct:]]//g
```

Comment: Exceptions are in html elements `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/9783734317873.css"/>
<img src="../images/9783734317873_140_1.jpg" alt="image" class="svg"/>
` how can we avoid this?

Answer (score 6):

Spaces aren't punctuation, and you aren't specific about whether you want to keep just spaces or all kinds of whitespace, but this substitution will remove all types of punctuation (since there are more forms of punctuation than just ! , and .).

`$string =~ s/[[:punct:]]//g;`

Comment: And there are more letters than a-zA-Z.

Comment: There are a lot more "letters" than just A to Z. That has nothing to do with the right answer though.

Comment: No need for the "i" modifier. I've never heard of upper/lower cased punctuation.

Comment: @runrig: yep, that was a holdover from my first answer which had `[^a-z]`.